# How to compute Spearman correlation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, metrics

## Problem

I need to compute the Pearson and Spearman correlations, and use it as metrics in tensorflow.

For Pearson, it's trivial :

```
tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(y_pred, y_true)
```

But for Spearman, I am clueless !

## What I tried :

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42730743/9494790) :

```
    samples = 1
    predictions_rank = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, k=samples, sorted=True, name='prediction_rank').indices
    real_rank = tf.nn.top_k(y_true, k=samples, sorted=True, name='real_rank').indices
    rank_diffs = predictions_rank - real_rank
    rank_diffs_squared_sum = tf.reduce_sum(rank_diffs * rank_diffs)
    six = tf.constant(6)
    one = tf.constant(1.0)
    numerator = tf.cast(six * rank_diffs_squared_sum, dtype=tf.float32)
    divider = tf.cast(samples * samples * samples - samples, dtype=tf.float32)
    spearman_batch = one - numerator / divider
```

But this return `NaN`...

---

Following the [definition of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Definition_and_calculation) :
 [image]

I tried :

```
size = tf.size(y_pred)
indice_of_ranks_pred = tf.nn.top_k(y_pred, k=size)[1]
indice_of_ranks_label = tf.nn.top_k(y_true, k=size)[1]
rank_pred = tf.nn.top_k(-indice_of_ranks_pred, k=size)[1]
rank_label = tf.nn.top_k(-indice_of_ranks_label, k=size)[1]
rank_pred = tf.to_float(rank_pred)
rank_label = tf.to_float(rank_label)
spearman = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(rank_pred, rank_label)
```

But running this I got the following error :

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: input
>   must have at least k columns. Had 1, needed 32
>
> [[{{node metrics/spearman/TopKV2}} = TopKV2[T=DT_FLOAT, sorted=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](lambda_1/add, metrics/pearson/pearson_r/variance_predictions/Size)]]

Answer (score 8):

One thing you can do is use Tensorflow's function `tf.py_function` to use with the 
`scipy.stats.spearmanr` and define the input and output like that:

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
def get_spearman_rankcor(y_true, y_pred):
     return ( tf.py_function(spearmanr, [tf.cast(y_pred, tf.float32), 
                       tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)], Tout = tf.float32) )
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been working around to implement directly the Spearman rank correlation coefficient in tensorflow following the definition of this website (https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/spearman-rank-correlation) and I have reached the following code (I share it just in case anyone found it useful).

```
@tf.function
def get_rank(y_pred):
  rank = tf.argsort(tf.argsort(y_pred, axis=-1, direction="ASCENDING"), axis=-1)+1 #+1 to get the rank starting in 1 instead of 0
  return rank

@tf.function
def sp_rank(x, y):
  cov = tfp.stats.covariance(x, y, sample_axis=0, event_axis=None)
  sd_x = tfp.stats.stddev(x, sample_axis=0, keepdims=False, name=None)
  sd_y = tfp.stats.stddev(y, sample_axis=0, keepdims=False, name=None)
  return 1-cov/(sd_x*sd_y) #1- because we want to minimize loss

@tf.function
def spearman_correlation(y_true, y_pred):
    #First we obtain the ranking of the predicted values
    y_pred_rank = tf.map_fn(lambda x: get_rank(x), y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    #Spearman rank correlation between each pair of samples:
    #Sample dim: (1, 8)
    #Batch of samples dim: (None, 8) None=batch_size=64
    #Output dim: (batch_size, ) = (64, )
    sp = tf.map_fn(lambda x: sp_rank(x[0],x[1]), (y_true, y_pred_rank), dtype=tf.float32)
    #Reduce to a single value
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(sp)
    return loss
```

Comment: very nice! Have you tried turning it into a Class, so that it can be used to monitor ranking correlation during training?

Answer (score 0):

`top_k().indices` returns indices of the best elements. Spearman needs ranks. They are different.

E.g. for the array [3, 1, 2]:

- `top_k().indices` returns `[1, 2, 0]`
- Spearman needs `[2, 0, 1]`.

You can get ranks with the following calls (using `tf.scatter_nd()`):

```
def my_spearman(y_pred, labels):
  predictions_rank = tf.argsort(tf.squeeze(y_pred))
  real_rank = tf.argsort(labels)
  r = tf.range(tf.shape(labels))
  real_rank = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(real_rank, -1), r, tf.shape(real_rank))
  predictions_rank = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(predictions_rank, -1), r, tf.shape(predictions_rank))
  rank_diffs = predictions_rank - real_rank
  rank_diffs_squared_sum = tf.reduce_sum(rank_diffs * rank_diffs)
  numerator = tf.cast(6 * rank_diffs_squared_sum, dtype=tf.float32)
  samples = tf.shape(rank_diffs)[0]
  divider = tf.cast(samples * samples * samples - samples, dtype=tf.float32)
  spearman = 1.0 - numerator / divider
  return spearman
```

Please note that this algorithm doesn't work if the elements are not unique. Instead, the Pearson correlation coefficient should be calculated on the ranks:

```
def correlationMetric(x, y):
  x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
  y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)
  n = tf.cast(tf.shape(x)[0], x.dtype)
  xsum = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=0)
  ysum = tf.reduce_sum(y, axis=0)
  xmean = xsum / n
  ymean = ysum / n
  xvar = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.squared_difference(x, xmean), axis=0)
  yvar = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.squared_difference(y, ymean), axis=0)
  cov = tf.reduce_sum((x - xmean) * (y - ymean), axis=0)
  corr = cov / tf.sqrt(xvar * yvar)
  return corr

def my_spearman(y_pred, labels):
  predictions_rank = tf.argsort(tf.squeeze(y_pred))
  real_rank = tf.argsort(labels)
  r = tf.range(tf.shape(labels))
  real_rank = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(real_rank, -1), r, tf.shape(real_rank))
  predictions_rank = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(predictions_rank, -1), r, tf.shape(predictions_rank))
  spearman = correlationMetric(real_rank, predictions_rank)
  return spearman
```